# Не могу обновить значение ListView

Tags: java, android

Обновляю через

```
public void Update(View v) {
    lv.setAdapter(null);
    titleList.clear();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view);
    new NewThread().execute();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

...

```
    public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private ListView lv;
        public Elements content;
        public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

            {
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view);
                new NewThread().execute();

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.pro_item, titleList);
            }
        }

        public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
                Document doc;
                try {

                    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://coinmarketdaddy.com/currencies/all").maxBodySize(0).get();
                    content = doc.select("tr");

                    titleList.clear();

                    for (Element contents : content) {
                        titleList.add(contents.text());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }}

        public void Update(View v) {

                lv.setAdapter(null);
                titleList.clear();

                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view);
                new NewThread().execute();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых имена методов пишут с маленькой буквы,  во вторых, в методе `Update()`  вы запускаете новый поток, и по завершению его работы хотите обновить данные в адаптере, но когда отработает строка `new NewThread(). execute()` запустится новый поток и сразу же отработает строка `adapter. notifyDataSetChanged()`, то есть,  когда вызовется эта строка поток, скорее всего, еще  будет выполнять свою работу и результат его работы уже не важен.  Чтобы ваш список обновился `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` надо вызывать в методе `onPostExecute()`.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter. notifyDataSetChanged() ;
        }}
```